# dbus error in emacs

Tags: emacs, dbus, notify

I am trying to use notify.el on OS X, but every time get next error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: dbus-message-type-method-call
```

emacs --debug-init gives next output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable dbus-message-type-method-call)
  dbus-call-method(:session "org.freedesktop.Notifications" "/org/freedesktop/DBus" "org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" "Ping")
  byte-code("\305^H!\203^S^@\306        \n^K\f\307\310^H&^G\202^Z^@\306 \n^K\f\307%?\207" [timeout bus service dbus-path-dbus dbus-interface-peer natnump dbus-call-method "Ping" :timeout] 8)
  dbus-ping(:session "org.freedesktop.Notifications")
  (and (require (quote dbus) nil t) (dbus-ping :session "org.freedesktop.Notifications"))
  (cond ((executable-find "growlnotify") (quote notify-via-growl)) ((and (require (quote dbus) nil t) (dbus-ping :session "org.freedesktop.Notifications")) (defvar notify-id 0 "Current D-Bus notification$
  (setq notify-method (cond ((executable-find "growlnotify") (quote notify-via-growl)) ((and (require (quote dbus) nil t) (dbus-ping :session "org.freedesktop.Notifications")) (defvar notify-id 0 "Curren$
  (cond ((null notify-method) (setq notify-method (cond ((executable-find "growlnotify") (quote notify-via-growl)) ((and (require (quote dbus) nil t) (dbus-ping :session "org.freedesktop.Notifications"))$
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-569235> nil "/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/packages/notify/notify.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3614
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/packages/notify/notify.el" "/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/packages/notify/notify.el" nil t)
  require(notify)
  (if (fboundp name) nil (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))) "packages/" (symbol-name name))) (require name))
  (progn (if (fboundp name) nil (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))) "packages/" (symbol-name name))) (require name)))
  (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq name (car --cl-var--)) (progn (if (fboundp name) nil (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))) "packages/" (sym$
  (let* ((--cl-var-- packages) (name nil)) (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq name (car --cl-var--)) (progn (if (fboundp name) nil (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat (file-name-directory (or load-file-n$
  (progn (let* ((--cl-var-- packages) (name nil)) (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq name (car --cl-var--)) (progn (if (fboundp name) nil (add-to-list (quote load-path) (concat (file-name-directory ...) "pa$
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1796
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/araeris/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202;^@\313\307\314\317#\203:^@\320\nB^R\321\202;^@\316\322^S\323^A\322\211#\210^K\322=\$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Does anyone knows how to handle it?

P. S. I already installed dbus via homebrew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to build Emacs with DBus support to actually use DBus.  On OS X, that's rather unusual, and I can't see what you'd want to use DBus support in Emacs for, given that nothing else uses DBus on OS X.

If you're just after notifications, though, you don't need DBus.  In fact, DBus won't give you notifications on OS X.

For notifications on OS X with [notify.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/notify.el), you need Growl.  Namely, you must purchase Growl in the AppStore, or build it yourself, and additionally install Growlnotifier from http://growl.info/downloads.

Comment: and then `(setq notify-method 'notify-via-growl)` (or failing growl, just set it to one of the options that isn't `'notify-via-dbus`)